# how to fix/edit an invisible function in R interaction session?

Tags: r

I want to temporarily modify the function `lattice:::print.trellis`. I can use `edit` to open the function code in editor but changes will be discarded after exit the editor (not the R session). I also tried `fix` but met the following error:

```
> fix(lattice:::print.trellis)
Error in fix(lattice:::print.trellis) : 'fix' requires a name
>
```

Can anybody explain the error? Is there anyway to modify this invisible function conveniently and temporarily (only effective in the current session)?

BTW, the `lattice` library is already loaded.

Comment: I'd read that you need to re-create the package to persist your changes. I need to do similar but am not keen on such an involved process for a change so minor.

Comment: @flodel cleared the confusion in the question.

Comment: I strongly recommend you copy the source to `print.trellis` and create a `myprint.trellis`   .  Modifying package functions will muck things up one day when you don't expect it (you'll have forgotten the mod is there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are functions `assignInNamespace` and `fixInNamespace` that allow doing what you say.  There is also the `edit` argument to the `trace` function which will let you edit a function in place.  Using `trace` has the advantage of making it easy to `untrace` and remove the changes that you made.